# Question using Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics

> A father has five distinct antiques and he is thinking of giving them to his two sons. In how 
>   many ways can he do so if it is possible that he may not necessarily give away all the five 
>   antiques. Also a son may or may not receive an antique.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a connection to Stirling numbers of the second kind. The parent has $3$ options for each antique: Giving it to one child, to the other, or not giving it away at all. These choices are independent, so there's a total of $3^5=243$ different possibilities.